# Matching a string with exactly two "=" characters on either side

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need a PHP regex to identify patterns like:

> == The Quick Brown Fox==

The regex cannot match, however:

> === The Quick Brown Fox===

I have the following regex constructed - I'm *so* close:

```
={2}[a-zA-z0-9 ]*={2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookbehind before and lookahead after like so:

```
(?<=^|[^=])={2}[a-zA-z0-9 ]*={2}(?=$|[^=])
```

**Edit:** Although this solution works, it is not as efficient as Justin's.

Comment: This one is so far so good.
You win due to speed, @ridgerunner
I think there are a few other variations people have posted that will work too. I'll try them out as well. Thanks for lookahead and lookbehind operator ideas.

Comment: Cheers for good sportsmanship, and +1 because your answer is still correct.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!=)==[a-zA-z0-9 ]*==(?!=)
```

I find the above to be the most readable way to do this. You can also use the following, which works essentially the same way:

```
==(?<!={3})[a-zA-z0-9 ]*(?!={3})==
```

This will also allow you to match multiple times in the same string, as long as there's a break (any non-`=` character) between them. For example, `==foo== ==bar==` should produce 2 matches, while `==foo====bar==` should produce none.

Comment: Yes, this negative lookaround solution eliminates the need to check for the start and end of string edge cases which my (inferior) answer requires. This answer should be selected as the best. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
^={2}[a-zA-z0-9\s]+={2}$
```

`\s` matches white space
`^` denotes the begining
`$` denote the end

Comment: You can also use [\w\s] as the character class.

Comment: @erisco: `\w` includes other characters as well depending on the locale setting.  For example, if using the french locale, accented characters will be matched (may or may not be wanted)...